# jQuery as Composer dependency, why I'm forced to specify a version?

Tags: jquery, composer-php

I want to manage jQuery using Composer.

I've added a custom repository and it's working fine. But why I need to specify a `version` and how to avoid this? The `url` will provide always the same stable version available and updating the version number all the time seems useless to me.

```
{
    "require": {
        "jquery/jquery": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.9.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By the way, you can use `components/jquery` instead of mapping yourself jquery ;).

Comment: Awesome to see a bunch of front end packages under the components namespace! Check here for more: https://packagist.org/packages/components/

Answer (score 0):

Because of that wrong version can break your code, due problem with deprecated functions, feature support or anything feature related.